# Graphical Predicate Builder in Xcode 4 with Core Data

Tags: core-data, xcode4, predicatebuilder

I am using Xcode 4, and I can't find a way to work with the graphical predicate builder. Is it still there? How do I use it? Where is the documentation on this?

Thanks

Comment: Any one got the solution....?????

Comment: You know, I can't find the dang thing either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In XCode 4, highlight your model, then:

Choose **Editor -> Add Fetch Request**

[image]

Then highlight it (rename if you like). The Predicate Builder is in the right pane:

[image]

Comment: What about for Fetched Properties?  I'm having trouble finding that.

Comment: I also cannot find it for use with fetched properties.  This is driving me nuts.  The docs seem to talk about interface elements that are no longer in 4.0 and show the 3.0 editor view

Comment: I already found this way of getting to the Predicate Builder but......how the hell do you set to  accept a variable?  The help docs do not help....Grrrrr!!!