# Predicate Builder for Fetched Properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, builder, predicate

Does anyone know how to access the Predicate Builder for fetched properties in Xcode 4?  The docs indicate that one needs to access it through the "The Browser View", but I thought this view went out with Xcode 3.  I can get to the Predicate Builder for Fetch Requests, but can't figure how to get to it for fetched properties.

There must be a solution.

Comment: Sounds like you're not the only one with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629349/graphical-predicate-builder-in-xcode-4-with-core-data

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode model designer add fetched property to an entity. In the rightmost panel you will see "Edit Predicate" button.

Comment: Are you sure that's in xCode 4 and not in xCode 3 ? I know where it is in 3, but can't seem to find it in 4...