# learning Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

my first question sorry if this is too basic. I followed the tutorial "Beginning iPhone 3 Development" and I'm now following "More iPhone 3 Development Tackling iPhone SDK" which a big number of chapters on Core Data.
I've had my part of problems since the books are using XCode 3 and I'm using Xcode 4 but until now I've been able to solve them. This one however....

In chapter 7 (for those with the book) we're trying to setup some fetched properties for an entity called Hero (one of those will find youngerHeroes). The tutorial says :

"Although the Predicate field is a text field, it’s not directly editable. Once you’ve created a predicate, it will show a string representation of that predicate, but you can’t actually type into the field. Instead, to set the predicate for this fetched property, you click the Edit Predicate button to enter Xcode’s predicate builder. Let’s do that now. Go ahead. It’s perfectly safe. No, seriously—click the darn button already."

However in Xcode 4, this text field IS Editable and there is no button to be found to bring up the predicate builder...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graphical Predicate Builder in Xcode 4 with Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629349/graphical-predicate-builder-in-xcode-4-with-core-data)

Comment: NOT a duplicate: that's Fetched Requests not Fetched Properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature appears to be missing from the current version of XCode 4.  The apple documentation refers specifically to this feature as do a number of online tutorials, my guess is that this feature was present in the beta but not in the full released version.

We ended up having to write the predicates manually, which is a pain at first but after a while becomes second nature.

Good Luck,