# (Compound) Predicate Builder in Xcode 4 -- Where is it?

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4, predicatebuilder

First off, this question is closely related to [Graphical Predicate Builder in Xcode 4 With Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629349/graphical-predicate-builder-in-xcode-4-with-core-data). **However**, I don't have a high enough rating to comment yet, and since I have no answer to offer, I'm asking a new question with *much more specific detail*.

I've been banging my head against the wall here, so I'm going to provide as much detail as I can...

**The problem**: The apple Core Data documentation is still referencing Xcode 3 and shows a highly sophisticated graphical [predicate builder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeCoreDataTools/Articles/xcdPredicateBuilder.html) for Fetched Properties and Fetch Request Templates. This includes the ability to graphically create compound predicates of arbitrary complexity, for example:

[image]

This is obviously a very powerful tool for effectively using Core Data, and as far as I ([and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629349/graphical-predicate-builder-in-xcode-4-with-core-data)) can tell, this functionality is either lost or impressively hidden away in Xcode 4.

Now, based on the above-linked SO question, we at least know that in XCode 4 if you add a Fetch Request:

[image]

You can subsequently access a *very basic* graphical predicate editor in the pane to the right:

[image]

But this graphical editor provides **none** of the sophisticated complexity indicated in the apple documentation (again apparently still tied to XCode 3). And, also as mentioned in the other SO question, this still doesn't answer the question of how to access *any* sort of graphical predicate builder for Fetched Properties.

As far as I can tell, if you add a Fetched Property, it appears in your Core Data editor, but offers no way to access the predicate builder. To expand:

**In Xcode 3** the detail pane offered an "Edit Predicate" button that opened the Predicate Builder:

[image]

Here is the comparable view in XCode 4:

[image]

As can be seen, there is no "Edit Predicate" button.

**The Question(s):**

1) Where are all these features in XCode 4? As shown above, the only thing even approaching a Predicate Builder I've found thus far is the **very** simple Fetch Request editor, which offers no compound/complex predicate abilities that I've been able to find.

And again, I want to be clear here: Unless I'm missing something obvious, this simple FetchRequest editor that appears in XC4 when you create a Fetch Request is **not** the answer to this question. The only conditional option it gives you is to chose whether [None/All/Any] of the following are true. This doesn't even approach the functionality of XCode 3's Predicate Builder, with complex relationships and optional variables, etc.

2) Same question, also and specifically for Fetched Properties.

I'm operating under the assumption that Apple didn't just remove the ability to graphically create sophisticated compound predicates in XCode 4, for both Fetched Properties and Fetch Request Templates. But I'm at the end of my rope trying to figure out where it's all hiding...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hold down the option key when using the predicate builder in Xcode 4. The + on the right will change to ... and will allow you to add additional sub-predicates. The arbitrary complexity is still there; it's just accessed differently.

**Edit:** It appears that in Xcode 4, the graphical predicate editor is only available for saved fetch requests, not fetched properties. For fetched properties, it looks like you just have to type out the predicate manually right now.

Comment: Wow, what an obscure way to add sub-predicates. I never would have figured that out, thanks a bunch BJ, really appreciate it. And as you're clearly more informed on this than I, I'm going to assume that you're correct about fetched properties and mark this as my accepted answer. But certainly if you discover a way to use the graphical editor for fetched properties as well, please let me know!

Comment: Murdock: The option-click behavior is actually standard behavior for NSPredicateEditor. You can use the same thing when building rules in Mail.app, for example.

Comment: BJ: Great to know. This current project is my first foray into Core Data, so some of this functionality still seems rather obscure to me. Overall though I'm really enjoying it; some fantastic built-in tools...

Comment: Wow, I've been searching for this answer for hours. Thanks. I never would have thought to use the option key.